# How to add environment variables within the meta tags inside public/index.html in creat-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

%ENV_VARIABLES%

I tried this and restarted create-react-app with npm start, its not working for me, any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting it inside index.html, do the following and the variables will be available inside your app (auto added to meta).

create a .env file

```
var=var_value
```

then install dotenv

```
npm install dotenv
```

put the following at the top of the file where you want to use env variable

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

You can access it like the following

```
process.env.var
```